# Accept two different subclasses with same @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inheritance, request-mapping

I have `WebDeviceInfo` and `IOSDeviceInfo` classes that are subclasses of `DeviceInfo`. How can I create a single endpoint in a Spring `@RestController` that will accept either `IOSDeviceInfo` or `WebDeviceInfo`?

**Attempt #1**

I tried to map the same `RequestMapping` to two different methods, one that would get called if the `RequestBody` could be mapped to a `WebDeviceInfo` and the other that would get called if the `RequestBody` could be mapped to a `IOSDeviceInfo`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register-device", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void registerWebDevice(@RequestBody final WebDeviceInfo webDeviceInfo) {
    //register web device
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/register-device", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void registerIOSDevice(@RequestBody final IOSDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo) {
    //register ios device
}
```

But this does not work, the second `RequestMapping` does not get registered and the application fails to start up because Spring sees that `/register-device` with the same `RequestMethod` and `MediaType` is already mapped to another method.

**Attempt #2**

Next, I tried accepting the superclass as the `RequestBody` and then casting it to the appropriate subclass.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register-device", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void registerDevice(@RequestBody final DeviceInfo deviceInfo) {
    if (deviceInfo instanceof WebDeviceInfo) {
        final WebDeviceInfo webDeviceInfo = (WebDeviceInfo) deviceInfo;
        //register web device
    } else if (deviceInfo instanceof IOSDeviceInfo) {
        final IOSDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = (IOSDeviceInfo) deviceInfo;
        //register ios device
    } else {
        logger.debug("Could not cast deviceInfo to WebDeviceInfo or IOSDeviceInfo");
    }
}
```

This does not work either. I always get:

> Could not cast deviceInfo to `WebDeviceInfo` or `IOSDeviceInfo`

**Attempt #3**

Finally, I tried just casting to the correct subclass inside a `try`/`catch`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register-device", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void registerDevice(@RequestBody final DeviceInfo deviceInfo) {
    try {
        final WebDeviceInfo webDeviceInfo = (WebDeviceInfo) deviceInfo);
        //register web device
    } catch (final ClassCastException ex) {
        try {
            final IOSDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = (IOSDeviceInfo) deviceInfo);
            //register ios device
        } catch (final ClassCastException ex2) {
            logger.debug("Could not cast deviceInfo to WebDeviceInfo or IOSDeviceInfo");
        }
    }
}
```

Again I get error:

> Could not cast deviceInfo to `WebDeviceInfo` or `IOSDeviceInfo`

Is there any way to accomplish this, or am I going to have to create two separate methods with two different `RequestMapping`s?

Comment: it doesn't work this way, you need to extend your httpMssagerConverter to `deserialize` the http request, which should be very easy, if you are using `jackson`

Comment: For your second and third attempts, how should Spring MVC decide to deserialize the content as either an `IOSDeviceInfo` or a `WebDeviceInfo`?

Comment: @Jaiwo99 do you have any example of how to override the default one that Spring provides?

Comment: how about accepting your RequestBody as a String and deserialise the json accordingly? you might need a flag to indicate whether it is IOSDeviceInfo or WebDeviceInfo, preferably a PathVariable

Answer (score 2):

Attempts #2 and #3 should work when you annotate the base class `DeviceInfo` with the correct Jackson annotations:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = IOSDeviceInfo.class, name = "ios"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = WebDeviceInfo.class, name = "web")
})
public abstract class DeviceInfo {
    [...]
}

class IOSDeviceInfo extends DeviceInfo {
    [...]
}

class WebDeviceInfo extends DeviceInfo {
    [...]
}
```

Then when you receive a request, the body will be deserialized into the correct subclass, either a IOSDeviceInfo or a WebDeviceInfo, depending on the 'type' parameter in the JSON body:

```
{
  type : "ios",
  [...]
}
```

Now you only need a single @RequestMapping method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register-device", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void registerDevice(@RequestBody final DeviceInfo deviceInfo) {
    if (deviceInfo instanceof WebDeviceInfo) {
        final WebDeviceInfo webDeviceInfo = (WebDeviceInfo) deviceInfo;
        //register web device
    } else if (deviceInfo instanceof IOSDeviceInfo) {
        final IOSDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = (IOSDeviceInfo) deviceInfo;
        //register ios device
    } else {
        logger.debug("Could not cast deviceInfo to WebDeviceInfo or IOSDeviceInfo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PathVariable` to the parameter to define which type you need to deserialize

```
public void registerDevice(@PathVariable("deviceType") String deviceType, @RequestBody final DeviceInfo deviceInfo) {

switch (deviceType){
...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same `@RequestMapping`, however, you still need something to differentiate them. By same, I mean the same name, path, and RequestMethod.

You can use the `params` argument in request mapping to differentiate them.

For example,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register-device", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
    params="device=android")
public void registerDevice(@RequestBody final WebDeviceInfo deviceInfo){

}


@RequestMapping(value = "/register-device", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,    
    params="device=ios")
public void registerDevice(@RequestBody final IOSDeviceInfo deviceInfo){

}
```

Then just add an extra parameter to the request with the key "device", and Spring will resolve the correct method.

e.g., if this were your original payload:

```
{
   deviceInfo : {..}
}
```

it would now be this:

```
{
    device : "ios",
    deviceInfo : {..}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for a value in the JSON payload. The `device` here would have to be be a request parameter, rather than a value in the POSTed JSON. This would require switching the URL to `/register-device?device=ios` or `/register-device?device=web`.